# how to stop Intent services in android

Tags: android, service

i have created one intent service. Now I want to stop that service from activity how to stop that service? My code is:

MyActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Intent intent = new Intent(this, myService.class);
intent.putExtra("myHand", new Messenger(this.myHand)); 
startService(intent);

}
```

myService.java

```
public class myService extends IntentService {

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

String signal = intent.getAction();
if (signal != null && signal.equals("stop")) {

stopSelf();

} else {
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {System.out.println("print")}, 0, 10000);

}

}
}
```

to stop service on click of button

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, myService.class);
in.setAction("stop");
stopService(in);
```

can anybody help me to stop service?

Comment: as given answers you can do one thing use a Boolean variable for sending status of service from Button Click and use your logic if false received from button click then do nothing i think service will automatic stop or if receive true then do some job.or if service if running

Comment: Thanks imaran khan. I have done at ur way as of now.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs for [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; **the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.**

In other words, you don't have to stop an `IntentService` - it will terminate itself when it has no more work to do.

**EDIT:**

Looking back at your code, it seems you don't wan't to stop the `IntentService` you want to stop the `TimerTask`???

```
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {System.out.println("print")}, 0, 10000);
```

I don't know what `t` is but I'm guessing it's a `Timer`. If that's the case it will be running with its own `Thread` and attempting to terminate the `IntentService` is pointless - kill the `Timer` instead.

Also, why are you using an `IntentService` to create any type of object which maintains its own thread of execution?

Comment: but he want to stop it on Button Click?

Comment: "In other words, you don't have to stop an IntentService - it will terminate itself when it has no more work to do.". @Squonk, this is not true, the service might run in foreground (playing musing) and then user have to stop it explicitly.

Comment: @miso : No. I stand by my statement. An `IntentService` will ALWAYS stop itself when it has finished the work it needs to do - look at the source code. As for using an `IntentService` to play music - that's definitely the wrong thing to do. If you want a service to play music then use the `Service` class - the `IntentService` class is not the right class to use.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to stop that service from activity how to stop that
>   service?

`IntentService` stops itself, you shouldn't, you can't call `stopSelf()`.

When all requests have been handled, the `IntentService` stops itself.

Comment: but he want to stop it on Button Click?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, `IntentHandler` creates a separate new thread, does its work, and kills itself.

So I don't think you need to explicitly stop it from an activity.